# Trying to write a query to get a list of posts and associated attachments

Tags: sql, postgresql, go

I'm writing a list endpoint using Go and sqlx.  This endpoint can also take filters.

I want to get a list of Posts and their associated Attachments.

I am struggling to figure out how I would go about doing this.

Here is a snippet of my `Post` model, and I am trying to get a slice of `Post`.

```
type Post struct {
  ID int `db:"id"`
  // ...
  Attachments []*Attachment
}
```

Here's `Attachment`

```
type Attachment struct {
  ID int `db:"id"`
  // ... 
}
```

I have already got my getOne endpoint working, where it was simple -

I just had to do a simple Select query to get the Post by id, and to get the associated attachments I just did a join of `attachments` and `posts_attachments`.

Unfortunately, I am struggling to figure out how I can get a list of Posts with Attachments when each Post could have either 0 or more than 0 attachments.

Is it easily possible to do this?  I am just looking for a tip on how I can start with the list part since I know how to get one, just not how to get many.

One approach I got was:

1. Get a list of posts.
2. For each id in that list, do the attachments lookup and if there are >0 append them to that post item's Attachment field.

However, is this bad?  It seems too easy but also amateur because its doing so many lookups per item (I cap at 50 results per lookup). :(

Comment: I'm not sure about sqlx but with the standard `database/sql` package you would just write two queries and execute each one, or you can also execute them both together and use the [`NextResultSet`](https://golang.org/pkg/database/sql/#Rows.NextResultSet) method. The first query would get the list of posts, the second would get the list of attachments associated with the posts from the first query, this can be done using a join and the same where clause as used in the first query. Then as you scan the rows in Go you collect the posts and then you collect the attachments and manually associate...

Comment: ... them with the already collected posts. You could collect the posts into a map for easier lookup, then you can associate each attachment with a post by looking up that post by using the map and the attachment's post_id.

Comment: Here's an example of what I meant in the previous comments https://play.golang.org/p/IO2wTPgbZKz. I haven't tested this approach myself so you may have to tweak it a little to make it do what you want.

Comment: An ORM like [gorm](http://gorm.io/) makes this easy by automating most of it.

Comment: Thx!  That works !